# how to stop loop once its execute

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem when my loop executes one time it has a button in the drawer called about us so when I pressed this button my loop run and show me the API response but whenever I click again its show me the increment of the data I only want one time when I press the button.

my function

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//fetch all data from aboutus
List<Aboutus> aboutus = [];
List addabout = [];
Future<List> infocompany() async {
  String url = "https://www.exaple.com/api";
  
  final response =
      await http.post(url, headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'});
  print(response.body.toString());
  final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseData.toString());
  var data1 = responseData['Data'];
  for (int i = 0; i < data1.length ?? 0; i++) {
    print("checkinloop");
    if (responseData['status'] == "true") {
      aboutus.add(Aboutus(
        title: data1[i]["title"],
        description: data1[i]["description"],
        image: data1[i]["image"],
      ));
    }
  }

  addabout = aboutus;
  return addabout;
}

class Aboutus {
  String title;
  String description;
  String image;
  Aboutus({this.title, this.description, this.image});
}
```

Here is my  dart file where I call this function in future builder

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lawyer_app/lawyerdrawer.dart';
import 'package:lawyer_app/models/aboutus.dart/aboutus.dart';
import '../models/userpost/fetchusers.dart';

class LawyerAboutUs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LawyerAboutUsState createState() => _LawyerAboutUsState();
}

class _LawyerAboutUsState extends State<LawyerAboutUs> {
  String title;
  String description;
  String image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 100;
    var width1 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100;

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: LawyerDrawer(),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
        child: AppBar(
          title: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, right: 5),
              child: Text("About us")),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff6762F1),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: infocompany(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else {
              print(snapshot.data.toString());
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: 100 * width1, // 380
                            height: 40 * height, // 155
                            child: Image.network(
                              '${snapshot.data[index].image.toString()}',
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 1.4 * height,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            // width: 100 * width1, // 380
                            // height: 38 * height, // 155
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '${snapshot.data[index].title}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            // width: 100 * width1, // 380
                            // height: 38 * height, // 155
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '${snapshot.data[index].description}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            // width: 100 * width1, // 380
                            // height: 38 * height, // 155
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

wait for a response thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `aboutus` already has data, if yes then break the loop, else add the data to `aboutus`

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < data1.length ?? 0; i++) {
    print("checkinloop");
    if(aboutus.length !== 0){
        break;
    }
    else (responseData['status'] == "true" ) {
      aboutus.add(Aboutus(
        title: data1[i]["title"],
        description: data1[i]["description"],
        image: data1[i]["image"],
      ));
    }
  }
```